# IIS web.config incapacitating a subfolder, but on one domain

Tags: iis, web-config

In a web.config, how can I incapacitate a specific page, which would be accessible for one subdomain only?

Example:

`*.domain.com/tsointsoin` is inaccessible all the time, for all users

`test.domain.com/tsointsoin` is accessible

`*.domain.com/*` are all accessible

Comment: Use URL Rewrite module and write a rule.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what should it looks like?

Comment: It depends on how you define "inaccessible". Play with it, and you should see it provides a lot of options.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!  Inaccessible means to me that any subdomain ..domain.com/tsointsoin makes a 404 error or anything that prevents executing this page, and that the page /tsointsoin is only executable by test.domain.com/tsointsoin

Comment: So, here is my understanding:  URL Rewrite can detect any subdomain accessing the page /tsointsoin and rewrite these different URLs to test.domain.com/tsointsoin. This last URL is executed on the server.  Am I correct?

Comment: I upvoted Lex Li's answer because it seems that it is a good advice, though I couldn't make it work for other issues.

Comment: As Mistake 1 shows https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 you can easily tell what domain the incoming requests belong to and then define rewrite action accordingly. For `test.domain.com/tsointsion`, do nothing, and for the other `*.domain.com/tsointsion`, you can return 404 responses as you wished. Whatever other issues you met, find existing posts on URL Rewrite and you should be able to fix them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment!  So, I wrote about my following issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015347/url-rewrite-not-executed-on-azure-several-projects and I am already wondering if I have a syntax problem with my rule...